# Добавить клас для определения айфона.

Tags: javascript, iphone

Нужно в body для айфона добавлять клас для определения:

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ) { 
       if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1) {
                $("body").addClass("ipnone");
       }
}
```

И это не работает.

Comment: ipnone - не опечатка ?

Answer (score 2):

Зачем этот кусок кода для определения Iphon'а

```
 if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1)
```

Поменяйте:

```
   if(navigator.userAgent.match('/iPhone/i') )$("body").addClass("ipnone");
```

И должно все заработать